# Mule DataWeave DB results to Arraylist of Objects

Tags: mule, resultset, dataweave

I am trying to convert a Db resultset into an ArrayList of "Flight" objects using DataWeave in Mule 3.7.3.

My Code is as shown below. I am no expert in DataWeave :(

```
%dw 1.0
%type user=:object {class: "java.util.ArrayList<MyFlightClass>"}
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    airlineName: payload01.airlineName,
    departureDate: payload01.takeOffDate as :string,
    destination: payload01.toAirport,
    origination: payload01.fromAirport,
    price: payload01.price as :number
})
```

Instead of getting an ArrayList of MyFlightClass, I am getting an ArrayList of LinkedHashMap.
I'm sure I'm missing something trivial :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign each as flight object

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    airlineName: payload01.airlineName,
    departureDate: payload01.takeOffDate as :string,
    destination: payload01.toAirport,
    origination: payload01.fromAirport,
    price: payload01.price as :number
} as :object {class: "com.mulesoft.training.Flight"})
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks!! I could have sworn I tried that :( :( For some reason, it was showing an error. I may have misplaced something. Appreciate it! Any way we can achieve this within the Transformer GUI? Without writing the code manually? The DataWeave GUI doesn't seem to be very intuitive.